# is it possible to put an if statement directly after the embed declaration

Tags: discord.js

if i  want to send a very specific embed, i need to have some if statements to check for some values before it sends the embed, but the question is : is it possible to check or iterate through something inside an embed declaration ?

something like this:

```
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
if (object.color){
    .setColor(object.color)}
if(object.info){
    .setDescription(`${object.info}`)}
```

if not, is there any way i could customize embed more.I really don't want to copy paste 100 embeds for 100 different scenarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this but you now need to call it on your `embed` variable, instead of just calling `.setColor()`.

Here is an example:

```js
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
if(object.color) {
    embed.setColor(object.color);
}
if(object.info) {
    embed.setDescription(`${object.info}`);
}
```